# How to "draw" a geometric shape on a 2-D meshgrid?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to do a simulation on Fraunhofer diffraction and for that purpose I chose to use numpy and matplotlib.  What I need to do, is to specify a 2D aperture function and for that I can create a meshgrid of x and y values and assign a function z(x,y), which in this case should be complex.  All this does not sound too complicated, but here's where I bump into a problem.

How do you define a rectangular, or a triangular piece inside a meshgrid, such that inside the geometric figure z=1 and outside z=0?

Minimal working example, where to begin:

```
#! /bin/usr/env python

# Import environment
import numpy as np

x_ = np.linspace(0,1,255)
y_ = np.linspace(0,1,255)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_,y_)
```

what to do next?

I tried to solve the problem differently:

- draw a figure using matplotlib
- encode the values of z by using different colours
- save the figure as a png
- import the png as a numpy array and decode the colours.

However, this puts severe restrictions on the values taken by the function z, which is the main reason I am searching for a different approach.

Thanks very much for anybody who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two easiest options are to either use [`matplotlib.nxutils.points_inside_poly`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/nxutils_api.html#matplotlib.nxutils.points_inside_poly) or to use [`mahotas.polygon.fill_polygon`](https://github.com/luispedro/mahotas/blob/master/mahotas/polygon.py#L78).  The latter is a bit faster, but requires installing `mahotas`.

As an example of the first option:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.nxutils import points_inside_poly

nx, ny = 10, 10
poly_verts = [(1,1), (5,1), (5,9),(3,2),(1,1)]

# Create vertex coordinates for each grid cell...
# (<0,0> is at the top left of the grid in this system)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nx), np.arange(ny))
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()

points = np.vstack((x,y)).T

grid = points_inside_poly(points, poly_verts)
grid = grid.reshape((ny,nx))

print grid
```

Which yields (a boolean numpy array):

```
[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]]
```

On a side note, `nxutils` is going to be depreciated at some point in favor of some of the path methods.  In the future, you'll probably want to do something along the lines of:

```
from matplotlib import path

...
p = path.Path(poly_verts)
grid = p.contains_points(points)
...
```

However, that's only in the github head at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. You made my day. :)